# Cannot Load Workbook from Excel File - Office.Interop.excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I'm using Office Interop for Excel Version `15.0.0.0`

There is no option to create a workbook from an Existing File.The old sample code uses the following method to create a workbook

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile(@"D:\MyExcel\SurfaceSample.xls");
```

This method --> `LoadFromFile` has been removed from the current library,also the `open` method is a delegate.I have refereed the documentation but cannot find a relevant method.

Comment: It is a bit too obvious that you should use Workbooks.Open().  "It is a delegate" is the kind of weirdo detail that requires repro code and a decent error message.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought `Workbook` was a Class .. but it seems its an interface... https://imgur.com/a/QTrMjRG

Answer (score 2):

The Office object models don't work the same as those of the .NET Framework. For one thing, the `New` keyword should never be used for anything except the `Application`.

In order to create a new object (copy) from an existing file, Office applications provide the `Add` method. So something more like:

```
Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(filePathToTemplate);
```

Comment: Thanks... What about this `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application myapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            myapp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Test\YourWorkbook.xlsx");` ?

Comment: @techno Yes, this syntax is correct - `new` may (only) be use with the `Application` object. Note, however, that if you use `Open` rather than `Add` that will *open the original file*. Any changes applied will change that file. `Add`enables you to make a *copy* of the file and any changes will not affect the original.